# R: get list of files but not of directories

Tags: r, list, file

In R how can I get a list of files in a folder, but not of the directories?

I have tried using `dir()`, `list.files()`, `list.dirs()` with different options,
but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
all.files <- list.files(rec=F)
all.files[!file.info(all.files)$isdir]
```

Another option (pattern for files with extensions, not so universal, of course):

```
Sys.glob("*.*")
```

Comment: Thanks I thought the was some built in function.. I got confused by the list.files function, not the best name choice.

Comment: Welldone! I had be searching this for a while and did not find it anywhere, although its very obvious. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this.

Comment: This works, but it may be suboptimal in certain circumstances. I was using a directory on OneDrive that was linked to Sharepoint, and R needed to download each file as part of file.info. If you have big files this could take a long time.

Comment: This is definitely a time when R is infuriating. Why wouldn't `include.dirs=FALSE` exclude dirs????

Answer (score 37):

```
setdiff(list.files(), list.dirs(recursive = FALSE, full.names = FALSE))
```

will do the trick.

Comment: I think this one is preferable, see my comment on the answer. This method may also be more accurate for me. I had 206 files + directories, I counted and 51 were dirs. This method produced 155 files which should be exactly right. The other one had 140. Perhaps the extra 15 are system files or something, I'm not sure, but this one had the more understandable and clearly correct result.

Comment: this does not work if you need the full names because the list.dirs puts 2 slashes in the path.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that base R does not have a direct method to do this is somewhat appalling. The fact that BASH doesn't have a direct way is also a bit odd.

In my opinion, the best R solution is to simply appeal to the shell:

```
filenames = system('ls -p | grep -v /', intern=T)
```

Explanation:

```
ls -p     Append "/" to end of directory names
grep -v   Exclude strings matching "/"
intern=T  store the output in the variable rather then printing to stdout
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution using a regular expression to exclude listings that don't have a "."

`list.files("dir_path",pattern="\\.")`

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
Filter(function(x) file_test("-f", x), list.files())
```

And if you want to get fully functional with library `functional`, then you can save a few keystrokes:

```
Filter(Curry(file_test, "-f"), list.files())
```

This latter one transforms `file_test` into a function with the first argument set to "-f", which is basically what we did in the first approach, but `Curry` does it more cleanly because of the lamentable decision to have the `function` keyword be so long (why not `f(x) {...}`???)

Answer (score 1):

So, I know that these are all old and that there was an accepted answer, but I tried most of them and none really worked.

Here is what I got:

1. Example of all files in a folder:

   ```
   files <- list.files("Training/Out/")
   ```
2. Output of that code:

   ```
   [1] "Filtered"           "Training_Chr01.txt" "Training_Chr02.txt" "Training_Chr03.txt"
   [5] "Training_Chr04.txt" "Training_Chr05.txt" "Training_Chr06.txt" "Training_Chr07.txt"
   [9] "Training_Chr08.txt" "Training_Chr09.txt" "Training_Chr10.txt"
   ```

Where the first one [1] is a directory

3. Ran this code to get only the files:

   ```
   files <- list.files("Training/Out",recursive = TRUE)
   ```
4. With this output:

   ```
   [1] "Training_Chr01.txt" "Training_Chr02.txt" "Training_Chr03.txt" "Training_Chr04.txt"
   [5] "Training_Chr05.txt" "Training_Chr06.txt" "Training_Chr07.txt" "Training_Chr08.txt"
   [9] "Training_Chr09.txt" "Training_Chr10.txt"
   ```

This is more or less to help someone who looks at this and was as confused as I was.

Comment: If you have files in "Filtered" then those will be listed too.  That may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small wrapper function that tackles precisely this problem:

```
list_files <- function(path = ".", pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names = TRUE, 
                       recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE, 
                       incl_dirs = FALSE){
  
  #Set incl_dirs = TRUE to revert to default list.files() behavior.

  if(path == ".") { path = getwd() }
  
  #Include directories if recursive is set.
  if(incl_dirs & recursive) { include.dirs = TRUE }
  
  #Needs to have full.names = TRUE in order to get full path to pass to dir.exists().
  files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = pattern, all.files = all.files, full.names = TRUE, 
                      recursive = recursive, ignore.case = ignore.case, include.dirs = include.dirs, 
                      no.. = no..)
  
  if(!incl_dirs){
    files <- files[!dir.exists(files)]
  }
  
  if(!full.names){
    return(basename(files))
  } else{
    return(files)
  }
  
}
```

With the following example directory structure:

```
dir_test_lvl0/
├── dir_test_lvl1
│   ├── dir_test_lvl2
│   │   ├── dir_test_lvl3
│   │   │   ├── dir_test_lvl4
│   │   │   └── file_test_lvl4
│   │   └── file_test_lvl3
│   └── file_test_lvl2
└── file_test_lvl1
```

The outputs would look like this, depending on whether `incl_dirs` and `recursive` are set (or not).

```
#No directories presented.
#Recursive.
list_files("dir_test_lvl0", incl_dirs = FALSE, recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE)
# [1] "file_test_lvl4" "file_test_lvl3" "file_test_lvl2" "file_test_lvl1"

#No directories presented.
#Non-Recursive.
list_files("dir_test_lvl0", incl_dirs = FALSE, recursive = FALSE, full.names = FALSE)
# [1] "file_test_lvl1"


#With directories presented (default list.files() behavior).
#Non-recursive.
list_files("dir_test_lvl0", incl_dirs = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, full.names = FALSE)
# [1] "dir_test_lvl1"  "file_test_lvl1"


#With directories presented (default list.files() behavior).
#Recursive.
list_files("dir_test_lvl0", incl_dirs = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE)
# [1] "dir_test_lvl1"  "dir_test_lvl2"  "dir_test_lvl3"  "dir_test_lvl4"  "file_test_lvl4"
# [6] "file_test_lvl3" "file_test_lvl2" "file_test_lvl1"
```

All other `list.files()` options are passed on to it faithfully by `list_files()`. The function has no external dependencies (`base R` only).

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to try a non-base R package try the [fs package](https://fs.r-lib.org/)

To get just the files in a directory

```
fs::dir_ls("dir_path", type = "file")
```