# Get list of files in a directory without subdirectory names

Tags: r

The base R function `list.files` lists all the files in a given path.

The default

```
aa <- list.files(path = ".")
```

Returns a vector of the names of everything in `.`, e.g.:

```
 [1] "dir1" "file1.R"
```

**I want it just to return `"file1.R"`.**

---

A clunky solution is if I call instead

```
bb <- list.files(path = ".", include.dirs = FALSE, recursive = TRUE)
```

I get

```
[1] "dir1/file2.R" "file1.R"
```

So I can get what I want by calling

```
intersect(aa, bb)

[1] "file1.R"
```

But it seems silly to create two objects and intersect them when I feel like `list.files` can probably give me this directly, I just can't figure out how.

Do you know?

Comment: use `pattern` ? `list.files(pattern = "\\.R$")`

Comment: Cool - will work if all files are .R. Wondering also if there is a more general solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22069095/r-get-list-of-files-but-not-of-directories I think this is what you want.

Comment: Yeah right - so clearly no direct way to get files ex dirs. Wacky!

Comment: While I don't disagree with the wackiness of it, the docs (`?list.files`) do clearly state for `include.dirs` that *"they always are in non-recursive"* file listings.

Comment: You could always do `aa[!dir.exists(aa)]`

Comment: @r2evans yep no qualms on that - the docs are clear for that argument - it's just really odd that this functionality isn't in-built

Answer (score 1):

Using `list.files(path = ".")` displays the files in the folder where you are currently working.

You are correct.  Using the `list.files()`function can provide additional information about the files in this folder. But getting that additional information using this function will require knowing something about regex.

Using the `list.files()` function with the metacharacter `$`  will return all of those .r files in this folder.  If there are other files ending with the letter r, then those files will also be returned.

The following will return those .r files you want, and this should provide an answer your question.

```
list.files(pattern = "r$")
```

Comment: This will also pick up a directory named `my_folder`. I don't think regex is a general solution to this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Gray, yes this is as was suggested in a comment above by Ronak Shah. It will be fine if and only if the folder only contains R files, but as I noted in response to Ronak, I was wondering if something more general exists